# How can i soundproof my room for music making ?

Tags: sound, homerecording

I was looking for a suggestion, how to soundproof my room with a budget. and it should be good, since i am recording vocal, instruments etc

My main job is to make cover song and our own song recordings for youtube. Not high end recording studio , i mean.

Can you suggest me some videos or any blogs to completely soundproff the room

thanks

Comment: You can't soundproof a room well on a budget. It's not possible. Spend your money renting time in a professional studio instead. You could build an entire new room that is partially sound-proofed, by hiring licensed professionals to design and build it, but that will cost thousands.

Comment: Let's hope your budget is somewhere like 10 grand, otherwise forget it.

Comment: What kind of noises and volumes are you trying to keep out? Are we talking about jack hammers or birds?

Comment: Basically, forget it. No-one's ever successfully done it on a tight budget. One option is to visit a rehearsal studio, and glean ideas from that. It's also not clear whether you want to stop sound *coming in* or *going out*!

Comment: I once spent 2 grand floating a room in a room inside a basement... managed to stop vocals & most guitar getting out, but not the bass amp/drum kit. Could do mixes down there, but not really 'all night recording'.

Answer (score 0):

Sound proofing can of course be done, but some things might be above your budget. There is a lot of discussion about this on different fora on the net, so you might do a bit of search. I suggest only one starting point here, the Sound-on-Sound magazine has done a number of articles on this (you might need to search a bit).

One solution is buy a sound booth. They tend to be a box within the room with sound insulation. There are several companies manufacturing and selling these. I give one link [here](http://www.acousticbooth-studiobox.com/application_practice.php?gclid=CjwKCAjw9qfZBRA5EiwAiq0AbfNYK3PfloYO75o3mNQ8QsijZbdw0bg12y7ASEIoRQ_G9yvTy3GLHBoCYW0QAvD_BwE) only as an example, not suggesting anything as a recommendation.

Another solution might be to build a small "box" with a bit of insulation, maybe only for your head. There are a few of these to buy ready made.

Yet another solution is to sound insulate your room. It takes a bit of material and knowledge. Basically the room needs to be "water-tight" as sound will enter any little small opening. In addition you would want to "float" walls, floor and roof from the surrounding building. Finally, as it is totally air-proof you need to add some mechanical ventilation with sound traps in both air entry and exit.

In the end it depends on how much you want to isolats yourself from the outside sounds, isolate the world outside from your sounds insida and/or get a good sound inside your recording studio.

Answer (score -1):

You're not going to get anything of any quality; that said, if you absolutely must use your room, there's a few minor things you can do to prevent outside noise, if you're not already doing them:

- *Close the door.* Seems obvious,but it's really important.
- *Close any windows.* Again, don't forget.
- *If you play a stringed instrument, mute the strings you aren't playing.* Unless that's the sound you're going for.
- *Try avoiding leaving silence in the music*, as any very quiet parts might give away outside noise. Of course, that's not always possible.
- *Get as many windows and doors in the house closed, too.* Outside, cars and construction can be quite loud.

  I'm sorry I can't give any real answer to the question of soundproofing, but those will probably help with noise reduction if you're not already doing them.

Comment: I guess it's not clear from the OP, but frankly, if you can't prevent traffic noise coming in, you've not a hope in hell of preventing your drum kit getting out ;-)

Comment: Yeah that's true :)